# Why did I get two notifications for the same question?

Tags: support, notifications, stack-exchange-button

I got two notifications for the same question asked on the meta site for the site where I am moderator, but I should be getting only one.

[image: screenshot]

- [Moderator Tools and Flag Disagreement](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1068/moderator-tools-and-flag-disagreement) was not asked by me, but I did answer it.
- Both the notifications are for a single question; there aren't two questions with the same title.
- The notifications are not for the question, and the answer. Even if one of the notifications were for the answer, the answer is mine, and I should not be notified.
- In the moment I asked this question, there weren't comments, deleted or not deleted.
- The question, or the answer has not been edited after the grace period; if consecutive edits cause the notification to be repeated, this should not be the case.

Why did I get two notifications?